# How can I check for pillarboxing and letterboxing in videos using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tkinter, computer-vision

I need to build a tool that can help me determine whether a video contains letterboxing or pillarboxing (the black or white lines on the sides), and also see if that letter/pillarboxing occupy more than 10% of the video.
Since the letterboxes will either be black or white, I though about explicitly check that the border means are black (<5) or white (>250) by looking for a column/row of black or white pixels.

I made a script with a GUI to upload the videos, but it's not working properly.It doesn't show the correct percentage. How could I do it more accurately?
This is my code:

```
from turtle import width
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Global variable to hold the result label
result_label = None

def calculate_border_size(video_path, border_pixels=20, black_threshold=5, white_threshold=250):
    # Open video capture
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    # Check if the video capture is successfully opened
    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise ValueError("Error: Could not open video file.")

    # Initialize variables to store cumulative results
    black_rows_sum = 0
    white_rows_sum = 0
    frame_count = 0
    height, width = None, None

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        if height is None or width is None:
            height, width = frame.shape[:2]

        # Extract the border regions
        border_regions = np.concatenate((frame[:, :border_pixels], frame[:, -border_pixels:]), axis=1)

        # Count black and white rows in the border regions
        black_rows = np.sum(np.sum(border_regions < black_threshold, axis=0) == frame.shape[0])
        white_rows = np.sum(np.sum(border_regions > white_threshold, axis=0) == frame.shape[0])

        # Accumulate results
        black_rows_sum += black_rows
        white_rows_sum += white_rows
        frame_count += 1

    cap.release()

    # Calculate the average black and white rows
    avg_black_rows = black_rows_sum / frame_count
    avg_white_rows = white_rows_sum / frame_count

   # Calculate the percentage of black rows compared to the whole screen height
    percentage_black_rows = (avg_black_rows / height) * 100
    percentage_white_rows = (avg_white_rows / height) * 100

    # Check if the percentage of black rows exceeds 20% of the screen height
    is_letterboxing = percentage_black_rows > 20 or percentage_white_rows > 20

    return is_letterboxing, percentage_white_rows, percentage_black_rows

# Function to handle the video upload button
def upload_video():
    video_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video files", "*.mp4;*.avi")])
    if video_path:
        analyze_video(video_path)

# Function to analyze the video and display results
def analyze_video(video_path):
    global result_label  # Declare result_label as a global variable
    try:
        is_letterboxing, percentage_white_rows, percentage_black_rows = calculate_border_size(video_path)
        result_label.config(text=f"Is Letterboxing: {is_letterboxing}\nPercentage Black Rows: {percentage_black_rows}\nPercentage White Rows: {percentage_white_rows}")
    except ValueError as e:
        result_label.config(text=str(e))

# GUI setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Video Analysis")

# Button to upload video
upload_button = tk.Button(root, text="Upload Video", command=upload_video)
upload_button.pack(pady=20)

# Label to display results
result_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
result_label.pack()

# Run the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Videos usually use lossy compression, could that cause issues? For example the letterbox pixels at the border might not be #000000, but rather #030302. If you wanted to account for that, you'd need to set a threshold and allow for a bit of variation, you can do that as extensively as you like.

Comment: Yes, I kept that in mind, I set a threshold for black = 5 and for white = 250.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are 300 frames in a video(1920x1080p) and only 61 frames (which is more than 20% of video) have a letter box of width 110(which is more than 10% for ) and rest of the frames have no black or white bar.
So here it should return True but your code will return False saying there's no Letter Box.

Here you could maintain a List till the end of stream where each frame number corresponds to a set of letter Box width and Pillar Box width for that frame and after the Stream End you could easily Analyze and conclude to the solution.
like this

```
0th Frame -> [[leftBar, RightBar],[TopBar, BottomBar]];
1st Frame -> [[leftBar, RightBar],[TopBar, BottomBar]];
.
.
.
.
259th Frame -> [[leftBar, RightBar],[TopBar, BottomBar]];
```

Now Iterate over all the Frame and make a list or Replace the same list with IsPillarBoxError and IsLetterBoxError with its percentage value of Box widths, then you will have two information bifurcated

1. Letter box/Pillar box percentage of each Frame
2. A flag value which will tell if the current frame is Error or not.

Analyzing both values will take you to a conclusion.